# Ruby: No such file or directory -- C:\Documents <LoadError>

Tags: ruby, windows-xp, cmd

I'm just learning Ruby and making a simple Hello World program, put for some reason the command prompt can not find the directory (which is C:\Documents and Settings\Matt\My Documents\Ruby Testing Zone\hello.rb). With the directory set to C:\Ruby193\bin, I tried to type this command to run my program:

```
ruby C:\Documents and Settings\Matt\My Documents\Ruby Testing Zone\hello.rb
```

And I end up with this error:

```
ruby: No such file or directory -- C:\Documents <LoadError>
```

I have checked many times to make sure I'm not misspelling any part of the file name. What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put double-quotes around the whole filename. Windows won't treat it as a single parameter otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In your open command, make sure that the spaces between `Documents`, `and`, and `Settings` are proceded with a backslash. In other words, here's what the path should be:

```
C:\\Documents\ and\ Settings\\Matt\\My\ Documents\\Ruby\ Testing\ Zone\\hello.rb
```

Or, replace the double-backslashes with slashes:

```
C:/Documents\ and\ Settings/Matt/My\ Documents/Ruby\ Testing\ Zone/hello.rb
```